# ¿Cómo concatenar columnas especificas en una tabla en python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tablas, concatenación

Estoy tratando de pasar unas tablas de pdf a data frame, sin embargo en el pdf se encuentran con espacios en las columnas, como se muestra en las fotos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando eliminar estos espacios con la ayuda de pandas, usando el siguiente código, sin embargo se me esta dificultando para cuando hay más de un espacio en blanco, ¿saben si hay alguna función que ya haga este trabajo?

```python
import camelot
import pandas as pd

pdf_path = ('https://www.sgg.chiapas.gob.mx/po2018/archivos/C-215-09032022-1548.pdf')

tables = camelot.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages = "1-3",  multiple_tables = True, flavor= 'stream')

df2 = tables[2].df


def remueve_espacios(t):
    temp =  ""
    for j in range(1,len(t)):
        temp = t[1][j]
        if (t[0][j] == ""):
            t[1][j-1] = t[1][j-1]+ " " + temp 
            t.drop(j, inplace=True) 
            
remueve_espacios(df2)
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con 'tabula'?  pip install tabula-py    pip install pandas  import tabula   #declare the path of your file
file_path = "/path/to/pdf_file/data.pdf"#Convert your file
df = tabula.read_pdf(file_path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Es una pregunta interesante

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una nueva columna (La llamo `group`) y hacer una condición para que `group` sea 1 en las filas donde la columna `0` no esté vacía

```
df.loc[~(df[0] == ''), 'group'] = 1
```

Luego agrupamos el `dataframe` de acuerdo a la columna `group` y para que cada grupo sea diferente hacemos `cumsum` (Eso va a ocasionar que `group` empiece en 1 y cada vez que haya un 1 en nuestra columna `group` va a sumar, entonces digamos que esto crea el `ID` del grupo)

```
g = df.group.fillna(0).cumsum()
```

Luego, en el `dataframe` original vamos a concatenar el texto de las filas que tienen el mismo `ID` del grupo con `transform(' '.join)` (Esto hace que todas las filas de la columna `1` que tengan el mismo `ID` de grupo tengan el mismo texto, pero ahora ya es el texto completo)

```
df[1] = df.groupby(g)[1].transform(' '.join)
```

Por último, creamos un nuevo `dataframe` para obtener únicamente las filas que tienen información en la columna `0`

```
new_df =  df.loc[~(df[0] == '')]
```

Si deseas eliminar la columna `group` puedes hacer

```
new_df = new_df.drop('group', axis=1)
```

El ejemplo completo:

```
import camelot
import pandas as pd

pdf_path = ('https://www.sgg.chiapas.gob.mx/po2018/archivos/C-215-09032022-1548.pdf')

tables = camelot.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages = "1-3",  multiple_tables = True, flavor= 'stream')

df = tables[2].df

df.loc[~(df[0] == ''), 'group'] = 1
g = df.group.fillna(0).cumsum()
df[1] = df.groupby(g)[1].transform(' '.join)
new_df =  df.loc[~(df[0] == '')]

new_df = new_df.drop('group', axis=1)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias me ayudo mucho, no se me hubiera ocurrido con una nueva columna, interesante solución.

Comment: @mirii99, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.